# Visual Studio - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: visual-studio, parsing, tryparse

I have a part of my code here (file parser program) that gives me an error of: **Input string was not in a correct format**

```
For Each h1 As Char In PRIM_BIT.ToCharArray

   rawbit = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(h1, 16), 2)
   pribitval = pribitval & StrDup(4 - rawbit.Length, "0") & rawbit

Next
```

I tried to use **int.TryParse**, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to parse this?

Comment: What does the input string look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `h1` when the error occurred.

`h1` has to be a valid digit. Such as 0 ~ 9, a ~ f, A ~ F.

Also, `h1` cannot be empty.

---

Edit:

If you want to bypass this and proceed, you can use `Try...Catch...` statement

```
For Each h1 As Char In PRIM_BIT.ToCharArray
    Try
        rawbit = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(h1, 16), 2)
        pribitval = pribitval & StrDup(4 - rawbit.Length, "0") & rawbit
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Do something when error occurs. Or simply do nothing.
    End Try
Next
```

I still recommend you to check what went wrong when the error occurred.

Comment: Assuming that h1 is not a valid digit, how can we bypass this and proceed to the process of the program, avoiding the error. Is there a way to do this? The file that is our source as input should not be changed (otherwise it cannot be processed as well)

Comment: You can use Try...Catch... Statement to do that.